# How can I update a bookmark using python?

Tags: python

I trying to update a bookmark called "OfficeNotesRefnum" in a Word document.
I have this, buy it creates new bookmark instead of updating the existing bookmark.

```
from docx import Document
import docx


def add_bookmark(paragraph, bookmark_text, bookmark_name):
    run = paragraph.add_run()
    tag = run._r

    start = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:bookmarkStart')
    start.set(docx.oxml.ns.qn('w:id'), '0')
    start.set(docx.oxml.ns.qn('w:name'), bookmark_name)
    tag.append(start)

    text = docx.oxml.OxmlElement('w:r')
    text.text = bookmark_text
    tag.append(text)

    end = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:bookmarkEnd')
    end.set(docx.oxml.ns.qn('w:id'), '0')
    end.set(docx.oxml.ns.qn('w:name'), bookmark_name)
    tag.append(end)

# test the functions
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # input test document
    doc = Document(r"C:/projects/template.docx")
    bookmark_title = ["OfficeNotesRefnum"]
    bookmark_value = ["005005-52545"]

    i = 0
    while i < len(bookmark_value):
        add_bookmark(doc.paragraphs[i], bookmark_text=f"{bookmark_value[i]}", bookmark_name=f"temp{bookmark_title[i]}", )
        i += 1
    # add_bookmark(paragraph = , bookmark_text=f"{bookmark_title}", bookmark_name=f"{bookmark_value}")

    doc.save(r"C:/project/reports/new_file.docx")
```